# How to define Hasura permissions via script

Tags: permissions, graphql, hasura

We deploy a Hasura Docker image as part of our build pipeline. The documentation only shows how to use the web UI to create permissions. Is there a way to setup permissions in an infrastructure-as-code way? I couldn't find any configuration files or database tables in which the permissions are persisted.

Answer (score 0):

The current permissions can be exported by running

```
 hasura metadata export --admin-secret <passwd> --endpoint http://localhost:8080
```

The `tables.yaml` will then contain permission definitions.